# Full access to class's elements , which contain into other class

Tags: java, class, oop

I think it's normal desire to have access for manipulating with data. Should i create getters/setters in `Record` class, if i already use `Storage` for this goal, made on `Record`? Or what need to do?

```
public class Storage {
    List<Record> record;

    public Storage(){
        this.record = new ArrayList<Record>();
    }

    public void addRecord(Record record) {
        this.record.add(record);
    }

    public Record getRecord(int number){
        return this.record.get(number);
    }


public class Record {
    private int number;
    private int count;
    private Object code;

  /*  public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }        */

    public Record(int number, int count, Object code) {
        this.number = number;
        this.count = count;
        this.code = code;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (this.number+" "+this.code+" "+ this.count);
    }
}
```

Comment: I really don't get what you are asking here. What do you want to access/manipulate?

Answer (score 0):

According to me **it is not require to write setter and getter methods until you don't want to modify them**.In your code you have initialized fields in constructor and overridden `toString()` method to get meaningful content of `Record` object and never trying to modify `Record` 's fields directly.
I strongly feel that it is not required.

Comment: `toString()` returns me `String`, for work i need interact with components of `Record`, for this situation still not need access all the elements?